# call function from one js file to another js file or HapiJs routes

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I have nodejs application where I am using HapiJS. I have below file in application

server.js

```
.........

var allRoutes = require('./AllRoutes');
server.route(allRoutes);

........

function testFunction(){
   //do something
}
```

AllRoutes.js

```
var myRoutes= require('./myRoutes.js');
module.exports = [].concat(myRoutes);
```

myRoutes.js

```
module.exports = [
{
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/test',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        var payload = request.payload; 
        testFunction();     <==== getting error here
        ........
        ........
}];
```

When I am trying to call testFunction() in myRoutes.js it is failing and giving

```
ReferenceError: testFunction is not defined
```

I have also tried to add below line in myRoutes.js but still same error.

```
var server = require('./server.js');
```

How I can call function from one js file to another js file or HapiJs routes?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to define a function and make it usable in every route, you should check [server methods](https://hapijs.com/tutorials/server-methods)

Be aware, those had to be registered as plugIn. If you use hapi 17, the way this is achieved is different than in other version

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would write testFunction in a separate file if you need to use in more than one place and then export function.  In node you can export function form file using the following method

**Helpers.js**

```
const testFunction = (arg1, arg2) = > {

    // function code
};

module.export = {

    testFunction,
    /// more functions or objects
};
```

You can then require from multiple places like shown below

**Server.js**

```
const Helpers = require('./helpers');
Helpers.testFunction();
```

**myRoutes.js**

```
const Helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = [{
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/test',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        const payload = request.payload; 
        Helpers.testFunction(); 
        ........
        ........

    };
}];
```